# Prove that a function does not have any (partial) weak derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, $N>1$, such that $f(x) = \vert x
 \vert^{-\alpha}$.

- How do I prove that $f \in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and that $f$ has **no weak partial derivatives** if $\alpha \ge N-1$?
- How do I prove that $f$ has all the first-order partial derivatives if $\alpha < N-1$ and how do I calculate them?

Comment: Look at the classical partial derivatives (on $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{0\}$). Off the origin, a weak derivative would have to coincide (almost everywhere) with that. But the classical partial derivatives aren't locally integrable.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why aren't they locally integrable?

Comment: @Riku not if the compact neighborhood contains $0$.

Comment: @Riku why? That is not what you have stated in your question. Just take a look for $N = 1$.

Comment: @user251257 Sorry, I thought you were referring to the comment above. So you're saying that the function in the question has no weak partial derivatives for $\alpha \ge N-1$ because the problem is at $0$. That is not quite clear to me. Can you provide some details in an answer? Also, what about the $\alpha < N-1$ case?

Comment: By definition $D^\alpha f$ must be locally integrable and $f$ has a singularity at $0$.

Comment: @user251257 What do you mean?

Comment: Ah. I meant $Df$. Say $N=1$ and $f(x) = |x|^{-1}$. Then, we have $Df(x) = -x^{-2}$ for $x>0$, which isn't integrable near $0$.

Comment: I see that I haven't expressed myself well. Sorry for that. As user251257 noted, the problem is at the origin, the only candidate for a weak derivative is a function that isn't integrable on any neighbourhood of the origin. $\partial_k \lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha} = -\alpha x_k \lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha-2}$ grows too fast near $0$.